# Facebook Watch and Instagram Reels not Working on AOSP 10.0 v209

Tags: facebook, instagram

I have a problem with my phone, and I need your help. I recently flashed [AOSP 10.0 v209](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/releases?q=AOSP+10.0+v209&expanded=true) on my Redmi Go (tiare) then I flashed [litegapps (systemless)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/litegapps/files/litegapps/arm/29/go/v2.7/) and everything was working fine until I tried to use Facebook Watch and Instagram Reels. They just don't load at all! I can see the thumbnails but when I tap on them, nothing happens. But they work fine in Facebook Lite and Instagram Lite. It's so frustrating because I love watching videos on these apps. I checked the permissions, and they are all granted. I cleared the cache and data, but it didn't help. I even tried to reinstall the apps, but it was useless. I even tried installing Meta Services and Meta App Manager using [App Systemizer v17.3.1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-terminal-app-systemizer-v17-3-1.3585851/) it improved the experience a bit, but the issue didn't solve at all. I don't understand why they are not working on AOSP 10.0 v209 when they were working perfectly on the stock rom. Does anyone have a solution for this? Please share your tips and tricks with me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first step when apps don't work is checking logcat for the error message. With a little programming and Android know how it is often obvious where the problem is located (base on Exception name, error message, stack trace...).

Comment: File a bug report with the developer of that ROM. Nothing we can do on our end. Facebook videos work fine on other devices running stable ROMs.